# Go race condition when closing a Go channel

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition, channel, goroutine

The following Go code example has a Race condition between the line `c <- byte(0)` and `close(c)`. It is signaled when the code is run with `go test -race`.

```
func TestRace(t *testing.T) {
    var c = make(chan byte, 20)
    go func() {
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r == nil {
                t.Error("expected panic error")
            }
        }()
        for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
            c <- byte(0)
        }
        t.Error("expected a panic")
    }()
    close(c)
}
```

How can I avoid this race condition ?

**Edit:** based on Icza suggestion in his comments, here is the solution:

```
func TestRace(t *testing.T) {
    var c = make(chan byte, 20)
    var done = make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
            select{
            case c <- byte(0):
            case <-done:
                close(c)
                return
        }
    }()
    close(done)
}
```

This won't have a race condition and will be clean. It's a stupid simple example. I was told the select adds an overhead, but I didn't look into it because it isn't relevant in my use case.

Comment: Moving `close(c)` up so that it executes before the goroutine removes the race condition. If, for whatever reason, the responsibilities of closing the channel and writing to it have to belong to different goroutines the race condition might always be there. WaitGroups and other locks might provide a safe way to do it though.

Answer (score 7):

Normally the goroutine that sends values on a channel is responsible to close it. Closing a channel is basically a signal that no more values will (can) be sent on it.

You are not doing this: your new goroutine is the one sending values on it, and your other goroutine is the one closing it.

To get rid of the race condition, simply use the channels as they were intended to: move the `close(c)` call to the goroutine that sends values on it, e.g.:

```
go func() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r == nil {
            fmt.Println("expected panic error")
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        c <- byte(0)
    }
    close(c)
    fmt.Println("expected a panic")
}()
for x := range c {
    fmt.Println("Received:", x)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7nch00YaYj).

Comment: I would go further and say that it's an error for a receiver to close a channel; there's a reason why [`close`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) doesn't work on a receive-only channel.

Comment: I didn't see how to test for race condition on the playgroud. The use case is a controller that wants to abort a pipeline processing to restart it for instance. There might be more than one source of data. Whatever source close the channel creates a race condition.  My example shows a blocked pipeline. Does it mean I can't reset a pipeline in Go ?

Comment: @chmike You can't "race-test" on the playground, save it and run the race detector locally. If you want to have multiple sources and have a "controller" to reset it, then you have to coordinate, synchronize the sources and the controller (the general solution to all race conditions: synchronization).

Comment: @icza I agree, but the channel is already a synchronized resource. It shouldn't cause a race condition. I understand closing is special, but it should be possible to close a channel with a Go routine blocked on write to it.

Comment: @chmike Look at it this way: sending on a closed channel panics. If you don't synchronize your sources and the controller, when the controller closes the channel, all the sources would panic when attempting to send another value on the channel. So to avoid panics, you should / have to synchronize anyway.

Comment: @icza, there is no way to know in advance if writing to a channel would block. So I don't see how I could use synchronization to restart a deadlocked pipeline for instance without creating a race condition. The application I'm writing is for a daemon that shouldn't crash. So I have to be able to recover form a pipeline deadlock (I assume). Maybe it's the race detection tool that is too picky and it's a false positive.

Comment: @chmike There is an easy solution to that: you may use a `select`, where one case is sending a value on the channel, and another case could be checking if the controller initiated a "reset".  This way it doesn't matter if sending on the channel would block. Broadcasting the "reset" may be done via `context.Context` or using a simple (another) channel.

Comment: @icza that looks like a good solution. I would have to add  a `done chan struct {}` to unblock writers with a select. instead of closing c I would close the done channel.

Comment: @chmike Yes, and when sources note this, they may break out of their loop, and call a `wg.Done()`. And the controller should call `wg.Wait()` to wait for all sources to abort their work, and after `wg.Wait()` returned may safely close the channel that sources use to send values on.